# Is there a way to download the "image" inside a canvas class?

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I'm setting up an HMI and my customer would love to see an img with some weatherdata on it (lets call it weatherImg). There is a site where we could get the weatherImg from (https://www.srf.ch/meteo/warnungen). I'm not an expert but it look like a canvas?

I'm new to this and I don't know if it is actually even possible with VBS/C script.

What I have found so far is something like this:

```
Set var = xHttp.document.getElementByID("ol-unselectable")

Set img = var.toDataURL("image/png")

xHttp.document.write("<img src=" +img+"/>)
```

What we want is to download the img (canvas?) And place it in our programm/gui/hmi whatever you want to call it.
Is there a way to do the downloading in background with the code above maybe, for VBScript?

Comment: @Gerhardh [tag:cscript] is the console version of [tag:wscript].

Comment: @Lankymart OK, thanks for the links.